# Apache mod_rewrite rule to convert URL of page, keeping parameters same

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I sent out a link in an email that had a typo in the URL. I need to make a quick change for tracking purposes so that any incoming hits to the URL are instead parsed to another URL.

From the link sent out:

```
/app/prog1.php?id=1234
```

To the version I want to track:

```
/app/prog2.php?id=1234
```

How do I set up a RewriteRule to handle such a transformation?

Answer (score 1):

This works.

RewriteRule ^app/prog1.php$ /app/prog2.php [L]

Answer (score 0):

- don't forget to turn on RewriteEngine
- more important: don't forget the **`QSA`** at the end of the RewriteRule (QSA = query string append = keep what's after the **`?`**):

Here's what should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /app/prog1.php$ /app/prog2.php [QSA,L]
```

And if you want to track it in your log, do a redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /app/prog1.php$ http://mywebsite/app/prog2.php [QSA,R,L]
```

(Not tested but it should work)